# Is there a way to get Campaign Type with Google Adwords Script?

Tags: google-ads-api

I´m creating a report with Adwords Script. I need to select the Campaigns from a account with all source of criteria like: Device (mobile, desktop, tablet) and Type of Campaign (Search only, Display Only, Video, etc..).

I´ve managed to find a way to get the information for device using:

```
  var campaign = campaignIterator.next();
  Logger.log("Name: " + campaign.getName() + " ID: " + campaign.getId());
  Logger.log("Clicks Desktop: " + campaign.targeting().platforms().desktop().get().next().getStatsFor("YESTERDAY").getClicks());
  Logger.log("Clicks Mobile: " + campaign.targeting().platforms().mobile().get().next().getStatsFor("YESTERDAY").getClicks());
  Logger.log("Clicks Tablet: " + campaign.targeting().platforms().tablet().get().next().getStatsFor("YESTERDAY").getClicks());
```

However, I can´t find a way to get the campaign based on their Type. The thing I want the most would be selecting campaigns based on their type. Something like:

```
var campaignIterator = AdWordsApp.campaigns().campaignTypes("search only").get();
```

//return all the "search only" campaigns

It would also help if there was a way to get the campaign type like:

```
var campaign = campaignIterator.next();
var campaignType = campaign.type();
//return the type of campaign eg. "Search Only"
```

Answer (score 1):

So far, the only solution I got was using a Campaign Performance Report.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/adwords-scripts/NB7Dj_gLYOs/zli0h-AfEQAJ

Comment: A few days after you shared this link, other user just gave this:

`var campaigns = AdWordsApp.campaigns().withCondition("Status = ENABLED").withCondition("AdvertisingChannelType = SEARCH").get();  //Only check Search campaigns  -  Or use IN [SEARCH, DISPLAY] etc`

Comment: Miguels hint worked for me in a Google Ads Script (although I only found documentation within Adwords API and not Google Ads Script).